# ImportError: No module named 'sha'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, sha

all, I tried to `import sha` in a `python` file, but got the error message when compiling the file.

```
ImportError: No module named 'sha'
```

I am using `pycharm 4.0.4` with `python 3.4.2` installed on `Win 7`. I am wondering how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `hashlib`, in any case.  `sha` has long been deprecated.

Comment: `import hashlib`, but when trying to use `hasher = hashlib.sha1` `hasher.update(somestring)`; I got a error: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'update'`, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: should be `hasher = hashlib.sha1()`